# Appointment Workflow Issue

Tags: ux-integration, appointment

We are fixing some UX issues on our site currently and would like to get some opinions as to what works best.

We received a few feedback from customers that said basically they were unsure where in the process they were. (As in creating an Appointment not site flow).

Here is a process flow as it is.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsIE6V.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

My thought is that the Create A Patient is that there needs to be visual progression of how the User moves through the Appointment Process. Either by a gradual Percent Bar or direct steps that highlight when you are on that step.

Thank you for your review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You need a Step Indicator

A [Google image search for 'UI step indicator'](https://www.google.com/search?q=wizard%20step&num=100&tbm=isch&imgil=P1sllBdOtu-6bM%253A%253Bud2ef_ewsDxhLM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fstackoverflow.com%25252Fquestions%25252F16813806%25252Fcreating-a-step-indicator-for-devexpress-wizard&source=iu&pf=m&fir=P1sllBdOtu-6bM%253A%252Cud2ef_ewsDxhLM%252C_&usg=__dFcEdJ9Wlb9vbSqWSUMpuWm8vbA%3D&biw=1920&bih=965&ved=0ahUKEwjztI741dLMAhWDbj4KHafcASgQyjcIMQ&ei=iXwzV7PMCIPd-QGnuYfAAg&safe=active&ssui=on#imgrc=P1sllBdOtu-6bM%3A) will give you dozens of patterns to choose from.

Here's the top result:

[image: UI Step Indicator]

Some use numbers, some use arrows. You'll have to work out what works best for you through the process of iterative design and testing.